# Changing the redirect path while script is running

Tags: bash, shell-script, cron, solaris

I have a script which always giving output where I have it redirected to a file, what I'm trying to do is to rotate the redirected file, below is where i start the script and redirect it:

```
.
somecode
.    
su - username -c "command >> /path/to/directory/output.txt" &
.
.
code continues..
```

and below is the crontab I'm trying to create:

```
cd /path/to/directory/
timestamp=`date "+%Y%m%d"`
mv ./output.txt ./logs/output.txt_$timestamp
touch output.txt
chmod 757 ./output.txt
gzip ./logs/output.txt_$timestamp
find ./logs/output.txt* -type f -mtime +2 | xargs rm
```

or this one also failed to do the job:

```
timestamp=`date "+%Y%m%d"`
cp ./output.txt ./logs/output.txt_$timestamp
echo "" > ./output.txt
gzip ./logs/output.txt_$timestamp
```

in the first code the original script fails and is no longer working, and in the second script it doesn't clean the output.txt file.

Is there a way to do it while keeping the script working ?
Note; I'm running Unix Solaris.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is typically done by adding a **[SIGHUP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal#POSIX_signals) handler which restarts the command** after some other command (typically `logrotate`) has moved the file. On *nix operating systems you can move files while they are being written to (I believe with the caveat that it has to still be on the same filesystem); the extra lines will be appended to the file in the new location.

Answer (score 0):

You really can't change a running process's redirected `stdout` and/or `stderr` to a new file (see note below) (That's one reason using redirected `stdout` or `stderr` as log files for long-running processes is a **bad** idea.)

When the process is started, the redirection elements of the command are executed by the shell that starts the process.  The target file is opened and created if necessary in the proper mode (append or overwrite), and possibly truncated to zero bytes depending on redirection mode.  Then the open file descriptor is passed to the child process.  That open file descriptor is the only link to the redirected file that the child process has - literally.  It's a link to the file.

And that's an important point - as a link directly to the file, the open descriptor is on par with the directory entry for the file - the "file name".  Changing that name or even deleting that directory entry - such as with the `rm` command - has absolutely no effect on the open file descriptor in the process.

@l0b0's answer is correct that processes that need to rotate logs tend to use `SIGHUP` handlers to do such rotations, but "rotating logs" is not really that simple in the case of redirected output - what does the new output file get named?  The child process has no idea of what the "name" of it's `stdout` and/or `stderr` are - and the output "file" might not even be a file in the first place.

Log rotation schemes have to be *designed* into the process - logging should to be integrated in such a way that log entries don't get lost in the midst of rotating the log file, for example.

(OK, it can be *possible* to change the `stdout`/`stderr` streams for a running process - but it's something that has to be - again - *designed* into the process.  It's not something an out-of-the-box binary such as `bash` will do automagically if you send it a `SIGHUP`...)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks alot all for you replies, couldn't find a way to do it, so as a workaround i setup the crontab to stop the original script, do the rotation and start it again at off peak.